# quick javascript question about a dropdown with onchange action

Tags: php, javascript, select, onchange

Using smarty, take a look at the code below:

```
            <select name="unitSelect" class="uniForm" id="unitSelect" style="width:1250px;" onchange="location.href='{$ABS_MANAGER_URL}/managerEditUnit.php?unit_id={$set[i].id}'; return false">
                    <option value="0" selected="selected">Select Unit</option>
                {section name=i loop=$set}
                    <option value="{$set[i].id}" >{$set[i].unitName}</option>
                {/section}
            </select>
```

What I want, is for the value in the options to load into the select onchange"" call, for the GET variable...  I can't figure out how to do this with javascript...any ideas anyone?

Thanks.

---

**UPDATE**

It wasn't easy, but between a few of your comments I got one working, thanks all:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function viewUnit(value) {

        var url = "managerEditUnit.php?unit_id="; 
        url += value;
        document.location.href=url;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
<select onchange="alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
    <option value="0">Option 1</option>
    <option value="1">Option 2</option>
    <option value="2">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

---

**EDIT:**

Sorry for the duplicate.

If you want to use it with a function:

```
function yourfunction(value) {
    alert(value);
}
```

And ofcourse change `alert` in the above HTML to `yourfunction`.

Answer (score 2):

You could get the value in the select object by doing this in the onchange event:

```
onchange="alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex]"
```

Since you can get that value, then you can dynamically build up your GET request. Some like this:

```
onchange="document.location.href='somepage.php?id=' this.options[this.selectedIndex];"
```

jQuery makes it even easier, you can just use:

```
onchange="alert($(this).val())"
```

Comment: no luck man... using this: `<select name="unitSelectMe" id="unitSelectMe" style="width:125px;" onchange="document.location.href='{$ABS_MANAGER_URL}/managerEditUnit.php?unit_id=' this.options[this.selectedIndex];">`  Basically the on-change doesn't do anything, nothing happens.     Also tried using `$(this).val()`

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
<select onchange="yourfunction(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
```

Comment: Hm, so you're calling a function?  WHat would the actual function look like in this case?  Sorry, I'm horrible at JS.

Answer (score -1):

I could suggest you to use following for getting  the value when select an option from dropdownlist -->

```
this.value
```

moving to your javascript means -->

```
onchange="JavaScript:userDefinedFunction(this.value);"
```

eg::

```
select name='state' onchange="JavaScript:userDefinedFunction(this.value);"
```